# Login into Google with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-signin

Say an user with the login: `abcdef@gmail.com` and the password: `1234567890`. How am I going to login into `google.com` with JavaScript? I searched around the Google, but they are all related to Google OAuth2, not that I wanted. Or it does not allow any of us login with this method?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the Google login?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Google OAuth2 or OpenIdProvider, that's the required method to truly use google.  Otherwise, you'd be breaking a security protocol.

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: but the oauth2 is only working after the Google is logged in. i wanted to login into Google just based with my login and password. that's all.

Comment: OpenId? But I want to login with Google Id.

Comment: you'll be using the following link https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID

Comment: i read it, but it doesn't seem useful. that is because i don't see an API for passing my password for login.

Comment: because that isn't a possibility.  OpenId means you'll be doing an Iframe normally to let the user log into Google directly, google will send you some information back token etc.  This replaces your login system and allows users to reuse their Google Account.